# Tippy.js popperInstance not working in v6

Tags: popper.js, tippyjs

I am using Tippy and Popper for a Cytoscape tooltip. I based my code off of [this demo](https://codepen.io/rbogard/pen/mdyRPew) which seems to be made for Tippy v5 and won't work in tippy v6. Specifically, the `instance.popperInstance` is always null. I have read [this migration guide](https://github.com/atomiks/tippyjs/blob/master/MIGRATION_GUIDE.md#5x-to-6x) which simply says the `popperInstance` API has changed and references the entire Popper docs which seemingly has no mention of anything useful.

If anyone has any knowledge of Tippy v6 or Popper, help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my current knowledge, the `instance.popperInstance` simply does not exist in v6. There are various other workarounds to this issue but essentially it is a deprecated property.

Though this may not be the most satisfactory answer, I believe it is sufficient and am accepting it for now until someone potentially comes and gives a more fleshed out one.